# Customize default directory display using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to customize the default listing of directory including the header and footer of the page. I tried to search this information however most of the information included how to disable the access to directories or provide the access to directories. My concern is to change the font, include some images in header(i.e change the layout of the page as it displays by default and also put a logout option)with directories being displayed.

any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I tried the following coding in .htaccess

Comment: AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile path of file.htpasswd
Require valid-user
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 3600
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 3600Options +Indexes
IndexOptions FancyIndexing

Answer (score 0):

I think this post might be helpful:
http://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/

Although, you mention above that you need to add a logout option as well, which means there will need to be some backend coding.  What programming language are you using?  It would be much easier to use the backend language (like PHP, .Net, Java, etc) to grab the contents of the files/directories, that way you have full control.  .htaccess files are nice, but with what you're trying to do, it seems to involve much more than the capabilities of only strictly using .htaccess files.

Either way, the post above should help you "change the font, include some images in the header and change the layout of the page", just not allow the login/logout.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it worked fine. I still have one more question. In the list of directories I see a folder called "Parent Directory" which is automatically generated and consists of files and folders of previous directory, how can i restrict access to it. I tried IndexIgnore and it didnt work cause the name of folder has space in it"Parent Derictory", any clue?

Comment: Then I'd place the htaccess file in the parent directory as well and create separate rules for it.  Either that or create the htaccess in the parent, to account for the child folder as well.